# Visualize line plot in violin plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Given a dataframe as below, i.e. categories a-c, ratios 0.1-0.2 and two samples with corresponding performance values.

```
   Category Ratio Sample Performance
0     a       0.1   0      12.2 
1     a       0.1   1      13.1
2     a       0.2   0      8.5
3     a       0.2   1      9.5
4     b       0.1   0      1.4
.     .        .    .       .
.     .        .    .       .
.     .        .    .       .
11    c       0.2   1      4.7
```

I want to create a violin plot, such that the x-axis is given by the `Ratio`, the y-axis corresponds to each `Performance`-value and split the category considering a and b. The plot resulting from the following code is included below (spanning more ratios).

```py
# delete category 'c' from dataframe
frame = frame[frame.Category != 'c']

# visualize violin plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.violinplot(x="Ratio", y="Performance", data=frame, palette='RdYlGn',hue='Category',split=True, ax=ax, inner="quart", cut=2, linewidth=1.5)
```

[image: violin plot]

Now, I include a line plot visualizing category c:

```py
# delete category 'a' and 'b' from dataframe
frame = frame[frame.Category != 'a']
frame = frame[frame.Category != 'b']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
# line plot for category 'c'
sns.lineplot(x="Ratio", y="Performance", data=frame, palette='deep', hue='Category', ax=ax)
```

[image: line plot]

I want to join both plots into one figure, such that the line plot will overlay the violin plots, however was not successful in doing so and would like some help.

Comment: Why do you create a new figure via `plt.subplots` if you want them to share the same axes?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide a dataframe which can be simply copied and a code which can be simply copied and run. Include the import commands. Save people's time

Comment: You're mixing a categorical with a numeric plot. That doesn't really work out well.